# How to remove rows that contain empty elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that includes full x & y columns but some z columns don't have any data (shown below)

```
     x            y            z
 246.590724   -24.380943     --
 246.593273   -24.381374     --
246.7051392 -24.33428028     --
 246.823241   -24.087254 7.2435
245.5418243 -21.65491486 7.1933
  246.39548 -23.40651445 7.2318
 246.605133   -24.390006     --
  246.67683   -24.440527     --
247.3474986  -24.2324699     --
  246.80526   -24.692698     --
244.7469482 -23.66201019 7.2379
```

How do I go about removing the rows with an empty z element such that only full x,y,z data is left?

Comment: Using `df[~df["z"].isna()]` would do the trick.

Comment: I've tried that and got the error: `AttributeError: 'MaskedColumn' object has no attribute 'isna'`

Comment: It would be best if you could provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we could use in order to regenerate your error in our machines.

Comment: Without giving the full dataset you can use the snippet I provided above. I then used the code: `data = ascii.read('data.csv')` then I'm trying to filter out the empty data using `data = data[~data["z"].isna()]`

Comment: What is the output of `df['z'].iloc[0]`? And its type?

Comment: Of course, nobody is looking for the full dataset and it is not safe to share it with anyone. The thing is if you show the part you get the error(and not the whole script or dataset), it would be much easier to find out what's going on. otherwise, it could be mysterious.

Comment: I don't think it's a specific error with the dataset or the code. I'm just looking for a way to filter out rows that contain an empty cell

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[246.590724  , -24.380943 , '--'],[500.590724  , -24.380943 ,    7.2318]],columns=['x','y','z'])
print(df[df["z"] != '--'])
```

**Output:** (Note: sample code has only 2 rows)

```
            x          y       z
1  500.590724 -24.380943  7.2318
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropna from Pandas:

```
df.dropna(subset=['z'], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

If the null/NaN values in your file are not really NaN as it seems the case, before using dropna you could load your data like this (assuming "--" corresponds to the pseudo NaN and that the separators are spaces):

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep='\s+', na_values="--")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities in your case. First of all, if the `--` is indicating the None values and not literally `--`. In this case, you can simply use:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df[~df["z"].isna()]
```

The second possibility is that the `--` values are literally `--`. So, in this case, you can simply use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df[df["z"] != "--"]
```

In either case, the result would be the same:

|  | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 246.823 | -24.0873 | 7.2435 |
| 4 | 245.542 | -21.6549 | 7.1933 |
| 5 | 246.395 | -23.4065 | 7.2318 |
| 10 | 244.747 | -23.662 | 7.2379 |